# trying to add more indexes to a 3d ajax array before postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi so am trying to create a dynamic ajax request data array according to elements that have a "Changed" dataset.

I have managed to add the extra index, but it is only adding the last one. I need to push each one. I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

```
let payload = {
    UpdateID: {
        Table: `newton_manual_loads`,
        Code: `nml`,
        Rows: {},
        Where: `nml_id = ` + LoadID
    }
};

let Changed = $(`[data-changed='true']`);
Changed.each(function (ix, element) {
      let id = $(element).attr(`id`);
      let value = $(element).val();

      payload.UpdateID.Rows = { [id]: value };

      console.log(id + `:` + value);
});
console.log(payload);

payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
$.ajax(`/libraries/ajax/Update.ajax.php`, {
    type: `POST`,
    data: { payload: payload },
    success: function (data) {
        /*rest of code*/
});
```

The output of this code is

[image]

And the output of the `Row:{}` needs to be

```
Rows: {
          nml_pod_number:20
          nml_loading_gross_weight:600
          nml_loading_nett_weight:15
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it is only adding the last one

Each iteration over-writes the same value:

```
payload.UpdateID.Rows = { [id]: value };
```

So any previous values are lost.  You can retain the previous values by including them in the assignment:

```
payload.UpdateID.Rows = { ...payload.UpdateID.Rows, [id]: value };
```

Or, instead of assigning, just add the property:

```
payload.UpdateID.Rows[id] = value;
```

Comment: You are a god send thank you. I used the `payload.UpdateID.Rows[id] = value;` I've done it before I think I was just having tunnel vision. Thank you so much. When I saw this I literally face palmed myself.